# Invariant Violation error when using Redux with react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-persist

When I run my react React Native & Expo app on my phone the following error is displayed:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

The code is:

```
import React from 'react'
import View from 'react-native'

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./redux/store";
const { store } = configureStore();


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View>
          ...
        </View>    
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

and the file ./redux/store is:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import user from "./userActions";

const middlewares = [thunk];

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage
};

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, {
  user
});

const configureStore = () => {
  let store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};

export default configureStore;
```

The dependencies I'm using are:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
"eslint": "^5.6.0",
"expo": "^30.0.1",
"native-base": "^2.8.1",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-redux": "^5.1.0",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Where am I wrong?

Update:
Changed the App.js code solved the issue. The new code is

```
import React from "react";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/es/integration/react";
import configureStore from "./redux/configureStore";

import AppContainer from "./components/AppContainer";

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoadingComplete } = this.state;
    if (!isLoadingComplete) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <AppContainer />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }

  _handleLoadingError = error => {
    console.log(error);
  };

  _handleFinishLoading = async () => {
    this.setState({
      isLoadingComplete: true
    });
  };
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

This section of your code is not correct!

```
import View from 'react-native'
```

Change it to this:

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
```

I hope this would work:)